# How to create categorized area map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, categorical-data

How to create  categorized area map in R ?

Most of the map examples are based on numeric dataset ,
but i want is a simple map to visualize w**hich country belongs to which group** .

```
dataset :
zone    food
China   apple
Japan   banana
Singapore apple
Algeria apple
Australia   orange
```

example in example
[image]

example in highchart

https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/category-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach should work with categories.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

mapData <- data.frame(
  country = c("CN", "JP", "SG", "DZ", "AU"),  
  fruit = c("apple", "banana", "apple", "apple", "orange")
)

series <- mapData %>% 
  group_by(name = fruit) %>% 
  do(data = list_parse(select(., country))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(color = c("green", "yellow", "orange"))

map <- download_map_data("custom/world")

highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(map = list(
    allAreas = FALSE,
    joinBy = c("iso-a2", "country"),
    mapData = map
  )) %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(series)
```

**Map**

[image: categories colored on map]